# How to get SID, Service Name and Port for Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, connection-string, tnsping

I have oracle database running on address xx.xx.xx.xx

I know login, password and initial catalog

I am trying to set up new connection in Oracle SQL Developer so I can access this database to take a look at it. In order to do that, I need to know SID or Service Name.

Long time ago I would run TNSPing.exe to get service name, but this program is not available any more. Oracle is not distributing it.

Is there a way to access this info somewhere?

Comment: Why not ask your DBA? tnsping would only work if you already had a tnsnames.ora file; and if you do then that would contain that info for the alias you use.

Comment: `tnsping.exe` is still available - it is just not part of the Oracle Instant Client. You get it if you download the full Client and enable option **Utilities** in the Oracle Universal Installer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the server, then you can determine how many processes the listener is running, what IP addresses and ports it is listening to.
An example for Linux.

```
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ ps -ef|grep tnslsnr
oracle    6090     1  0  2015 ?        01:11:39 /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
oracle    6712  6653  0 05:59 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tnslsnr
oracle   17064     1  0  2017 ?        00:19:15 /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER_SSPS -inherit
```

If the variable `$TNS_ADMIN` is defined, it will override `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`

```
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ env |grep ORA
ORACLE_UNQNAME=ssps_db2
ORACLE_SID=ssps
ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/database
ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ env |grep TNS
TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$
```

For a start you can make a SQL query

```
select * from v$listener_network;

LOCAL LISTENER  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=krw-ssps-db-02)(PORT=1521))
SERVICE NAME    ssps_db2
SERVICE NAME    ssps_db2


[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8F:78:59
          inet addr:10.*.*.244  Bcast:10.*.*.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          ...

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:8F:78:59
          inet addr:10.*.*.242  Bcast:10.*.*.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          .....


[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ lsnrctl status LISTENER

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-JUN-2018 06:00:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                04-DEC-2015 08:48:38
Uptime                    419 days 18 hr. 44 min. 17 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/database/diag/tnslsnr/krw-ssps-db-02/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.*.*.244)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ssps" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "sspsXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ssps_db2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ lsnrctl status LISTENER_SSPS

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-JUN-2018 06:01:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1525)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_SSPS
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                11-DEC-2017 06:37:30
Uptime                    178 days 23 hr. 23 min. 42 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/database/diag/tnslsnr/krw-ssps-db-02/listener_ssps/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1525)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.*.*.242)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "asut" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "asut", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ssps" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "tch7" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tch7", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "tch8" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tch8", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ lsnrctl services LISTENER_SSPS

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-JUN-2018 06:02:24

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1525)))
Services Summary...
Service "asut" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "asut", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:102970 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "ssps" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:222841 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "tch7" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tch7", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:107112 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "tch8" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "tch8", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:102970 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 ~]$ lsnrctl services LISTENER

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 08-JUN-2018 06:04:10

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ssps" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:47 refused:8
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "sspsXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: krw-ssps-db-02, pid: 16980>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=krw-ssps-db-02)(PORT=53933))
Service "ssps_db2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ssps", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:103158 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Example of a listener.ora

```
[oracle@krw-ssps-db-02 admin]$  more listener.ora

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.*.*.244)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ssps)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (SID_NAME = ssps)
    )
  )

LISTENER_SSPS =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1525))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.*.*.242)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER_SSPS =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ssps)
        (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (SID_NAME = ssps)
    )
     (SID_DESC=
        (SID_NAME=tch8)
        (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
          )
    (SID_DESC=
         (SID_NAME=tch7)
         (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
         (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
         )
     (SID_DESC=
        (SID_NAME=asut)
        (ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
        (PROGRAM=dg4msql)
       )
  )


ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /home/oracle/database
```

Example the name of the service `ssps_db3` is incorrect. 
The utility tnsping diagnoses only the answer of the listener to the address and port. The correctness of the service name is not checked.

```
C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin>tnsping ssps_db 3

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-JUN-2018 11:43:29

Copyright (c) 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.*.*.244)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ssps_db3)))
OK (20 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)

C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin>sqlplus system@ssps_db

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jun 9 11:43:38 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener could not resolve SERVICE_NAME given in connect
descriptor
```

Log unsuccessful connection in the log file listener.log

```
09-JUN-2018 11:43:29 * ping * 0
09-JUN-2018 11:43:29 * ping * 0
09-JUN-2018 11:43:29 * ping * 0
Sat Jun 09 11:43:45 2018
09-JUN-2018 11:43:45 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ssps_db3)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\ora92\bin\sqlplus.EXE)(HOST=DEMIN)(USER=DeminDV))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.*.*.45)(PORT=61522)) * establish * ssps_db3 * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Example the name of the service `ssps_db2` is correct
    C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin>tnsping ssps_db 3

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-JUN-2018 11:45:18

Copyright (c) 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.89.251.244)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ssps_db2)))
OK (0 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)

C:\oracle\ora92\network\admin>sqlplus system@ssps_db

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jun 9 11:45:23 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

[krw-ssps-db-02.krw.rzd] system@ssps>
```

Log successful connection in the log file listener.log

```
09-JUN-2018 11:45:18 * ping * 0
09-JUN-2018 11:45:18 * ping * 0
09-JUN-2018 11:45:18 * ping * 0
Sat Jun 09 11:45:28 2018
09-JUN-2018 11:45:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ssps_db2)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\ora92\bin\sqlplus.EXE)(HOST=DEMIN)(USER=DeminDV))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.*.*.45)(PORT=61529)) * establish * ssps_db2 * 0
```

Comment: Just "select * from v$listener_network;" alone is enough!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an OS login to the database server you can run:

lsnrctl status

to get details of what the listener is offering out.  Or you can query the database itself if you can logon locally

```
SQL> select name from dba_services;

NAME
---------------------------------------
SYS$BACKGROUND
SYS$USERS
db122XDB
db122
```

But if you have no access other than the IP address, then you'll need to ask someone (DBA) for the service name.  As Alex said, tnsping doesnt "reveal" anything, it simply tries to connect to a service name that you already have knowledge of.

Answer (score 1):

'Cause you've said that you have "I know login, password and initial catalog". Then I said:

Get Oracle SID: `$ ps -ef | grep pmon`; (or `$ cat /etc/oratab` - format: `ORACLE_SID:ORACLE_HOME`)

Get Service Name: `$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`.
With tnsnames.ora format, you can cat SERVICE_NAME

```
net_service_name= 
 (DESCRIPTION= 
   (ADDRESS=(protocol_address_information))
   (CONNECT_DATA= 
     (SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

In order to execute tnsping, you can install Oracle Client appropriate to your machine.